# Storing semver version strings in postgresql database for range queries

Tags: javascript, postgresql, algorithm, serialization

The application that I am building has the requirement of showing specific content to users whose app version matches the range specified for the content record.

The application uses semantic versioning (e.g. `1.2.3`, `1.0.1`, `3.7.5`).

I want to convert the string value of `1.2.3` to an integer so I can create a range column that holds the min and max version for convenient querying.

Currently I am using the following javascript implementation which results in large numbers and also limits me in the minor and patch version to 999 (the latter is actually okay for me).

```
export function convertVersionToInt(version) {
  const parts = version.split('.')
  if (parts.length !== 3) {
    throw new Error('Received invalid version string')
  }
  parts.forEach(part => {
    if (part.length > 3) {
      throw new Error(`Version string invalid, ${part} is too large.`)
    }
  })
  const [major, minor, patch] = parts
  return parseInt(
    [major, minor.padStart(3, '0'), patch.padStart(3, '0')].join(''),
    10
  )
}

export function convertIntVersionToString(v) {
  const stringifiedNumber = String(v).padStart(7, '0')

  const length = stringifiedNumber.length
  const patch = parseInt(stringifiedNumber.substr(length - 3, 3), 10)
  const minor = parseInt(stringifiedNumber.substr(length - 6, 3), 10)
  const major = stringifiedNumber.substr(0, length - 6)
  return `${major}.${minor}.${patch}`
}

const v120 = convertVersionToInt('1.2.0')
const v120S = convertIntVersionToString(v120)
console.log(v120, v120S) // 1002000 '1.2.0'
const v1121 = convertVersionToInt('11.2.1')
const v1121S = convertIntVersionToString(v1121)
console.log(v1121, v1121S) // 11002001 '11.2.0'
const v001 = convertVersionToInt('0.0.1')
const v001s = convertIntVersionToString(v001)
console.log(v001, v001s) // 1 '0.0.1'
```

I want to know if there is a more efficient way to serialize the semver version to an integer (or other value that allows range queries). A restriction in the amount of digits per version part (major, minor, patch) is fine, however the produced numbers must increase correctly. E.g. number produced by `1.2.0` must be higher than `0.0.1`.

Thank you in advance for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have control over your database schema, pg-semver might be useful for you: https://github.com/theory/pg-semver It allows for a semver data type, and you can use the expected comparison operators to achieve your version checks.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible with AWS RDS .